# Google places autocomplete - limit number of results

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I there any way to display fewer results than 5 (default) in google places autocomplete?

Comment: Just programmatically show less results! I don't see what is your problem here.

Comment: The problem is that I can't see any option to do that. I'm talking about the google autocomplete which automaticaly turn input into auto complete not any custom code with API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to display less than 5 results that I am familiar with, you could however use css to change the height of the autocomplete dropdown.

The `div` that holds the autocomplete results is styled using the pac-container class which already has overflow set to hidden, so if you set the height to something like 50px any results that fill the div past 50px will be hidden. On the [example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) this will hide the last two results and show only three.

```
.pac-container {
  height: 50px;
}
```

If just want to change the height of the dropdown and allow the user to scroll down to see extra results you can set the height to something like 50px and set overflow-y to scroll.

```
.pac-container {
  height: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is what I used so I was just searching for a cleaner sulotion which would load less data... Thank

Comment: Undocumented = bad solution.

Answer (score -1):

With modern css you can even limit the amount of the displayed results.
For example 3 results:

```
.pac-item { display: none; }
.pac-item:nth-child(-n+3) { display: block; }
```

Or something in between :-) https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Documentation of html class names can be found on the official Google page: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#style-autocomplete